# Objective C - Populate Array From Exceedingly large PList

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

I am having some trouble populating a large plist into an array. Here is the snippet of code giving me problems:

```
// Populate the routes.
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"routes" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *routes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"Routes: %@", routes);

// Populate the trips.
NSString *filePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"trips" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *trips = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath2];
NSLog(@"Trips: %@", trips);
```

My issue is that after displaying each mutable array in the logs, the log for the routes array displays just fine, but the log for the trips array simply doesn't appear at all. Usually when an issue occurs then the log will show something like "Trips: (  )", but that line doesn't appear at all in this case. The only difference I can see between the two instances is that the routes plist is an array with about 1000 dictionary objects and the trips plist has nearly 92,000 objects. Is there some sort of limit on the size of plists?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you giving the system enough time to process the second list (i.e. not terminating the app before it could finish)? Does your program crash, or just not output the log line? There's nothing in principle wrong with huge NSMutableArrays, and even 92k items shouldn't really stress an iPhone if the items are small. If the items are large, you may be running out of memory.

Comment: The application does not exit or terminate in any way due to this. Displaying additional logs or performing additional operations after this run without issue. It seems to take a roughly 3 seconds to do what I would think is the data retrieval, but then simply skips it and moves on.

Comment: Something that might be obvious: Is the trips.plist added in the app bundle?

Comment: Hmm. I can't see why you wouldn't get at least a log line of "Trips: (nil)" or similar. Seems very odd.

Comment: @Francisco: The trips file is indeed added to the app bundle. 
@Adam: That's whats worrying me the most. I can't think of anything that would do this without also causing the application to crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > "Is there some sort of limit on the size of plists?"

There isn't a limit to to the size of plists, but there is a limit to the amount of data that you can feed to an `NSLog()` command.

If `trips` were actually `nil`, the `NSLog()` call would succeed, and simply print out `(null)`. The `trips` array is populated, however, which is why it's not printing out at all: `NSLog()` is saying, "sorry, there's no way I'm going to let you to print out all that".

I believe this has likely changed in more recent versions of OS X due to possible security concerns or performance issues. (In the past, users' hard drives would fill up with log files that were GB in size, caused by one process logging an error message hundreds of times a second; that is now limited to 500 logs per second). It's kind of confusing why nothing is printed out and you get no feedback from Xcode or anything, but I guess the system has no way of knowing whether your use of `NSLog()` is with good intentions or not.

Comment: You were right! I tried logging the count of the array and it gave me back the appropriate value. Then I rechecked my filter for the trips and it turns out I forgot to use stringWithFormat in my predicate to so I could set the filter value appropriately. After changing it I'm getting back all the right data. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc, if there is a parse problem or there is an issue with opening the file, nil will be returned. Is it possible in that massive file there is a bad character or a typo that might break the xml?

"
  Return Value -->
  An array containing the contents of the file specified by aPath. Returns nil if the file   can’t be opened or if the contents of the file can’t be parsed into an array.

Comment: That couldn't be it because then the log would output a null pointer (null). Thanks for the response though.